# Can paramedics revive civilians?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA 4 I liked beating up people, after which I called 911 to request an ambulance. After the paramedics got the people on their feet again I continued beating them up.

This does not seem to work in GTA 5/Online. Beating with fists, shooting legs, hitting with cars. Everything seems to be lethal. Still an ambulance drives up and checks out the bodies. They make some comment about the guy being dead and just drive away.

Is it possible to injure people in any way, causing the paramedics to actually do something?

Comment: The funniest stuff on stack exchange so far. Thanks man!

Comment: I assumed when I clicked this it was about Cities: Skylines (which I haven't played, but there are tons of questions about how fire engines work in it, so an ambulance question wouldn't have been out of the ordinary).  But no, it's GTA.  ^_^

Comment: @gatherer818 Grand Theft Auto: Skylines

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [Wikia](http://gta.wikia.com/Paramedics#GTA_V) it is possible:

> Instead of only the ambulance's passenger, both paramedics will now tend to the injured. Due to the absence of the injury system, the revival attempt has been made simpler. **Now, the change of revival is simply random**. If the paramedics are not successful in reviving the deceased, they will now stand around the body while one examines the body and the other files a report. Pedestrians may gather around the body and watch, while police may arrive in the case of many murders. **If revival is possible, the injured will enter the ambulance with the help of the paramedics and will be driven to hospital.**

This indicates it IS possible for a pedestrian to be revived by paramedics. You (or actually the pedestrians) are just very unlucky so it seems.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll just have to shoot some more legs then. I'll wait a while with accepting the answer in case anyone has some more experience or information about it.

Comment: There are a lot of posts of people complaining of how quick pedestrians die, and that is not realistic. So you are not the only one noticing this 'problem'

Comment: By the way, you are a sadist :P

Comment: I don't really mind that they die fast. It just adds to the immersion to see medics actually taking injured people to the hospital. If a lot of things happen in the city, including random events, it really feels more alive. (In this case I was the cause, but I'm doing it for science.)

Comment: I would beat the paramedics for not being able to revive your victims

Comment: @Jubatus Oh I do. Same with the paramedics who arrive a bit later to help them. Etc.